# Is it possible to update a lattice panel in R?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

The `update` method of `trellis` plots allows one to modify a `lattice` plot after the initial call.  But the `update` behaviour is more like replace than append. This differs from the `ggplot2` idiom where each new layer is additive to what exists already. Is it possible to get this additive behaviour using `lattice`?

An example:

```
LL <- barchart(yield ~ variety | site, data = barley,
        groups = year, stack = TRUE,
        between=list(y=0.5),
        scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)))
print(LL)
```

[image]

Now I want to add `panel.text` to the existing plot.  Using `update` in the following way doesn't work:

```
update(LL, panel=function(...){
           args <- list(...); panel.text(args$x, args$y+2, round(args$y, 0))
         })
```

[image]

I know that I can use `update` by specifying all of the layers in the panel function:

```
update(LL, panel=function(...){
           args <- list(...)
           panel.barchart(...)
           panel.text(args$x, args$y+2, round(args$y, 0))
         })
```

This will work, but requires that I know what is already in the `lattice` plot - or that I refactor my code quite substantially.

**Question:** Is there a way of adding to the existing panel in `update.trellis`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See `layer` from the [`latticeExtra`](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#layer&theme=default) package.

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
LL <- barchart(yield ~ variety | site, data = barley,
        groups = year, stack = TRUE,
        between=list(y=0.5),
        scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)))
LL + layer(panel.text(x, y, round(y, 0), data=barley))
```

[image: result of code]

Comment: +1 for a helpful tip (and for fixing the missing 90 in my code!)

Comment: There is nice [latticeExtra introduction page](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org).

Comment: Interesting aside: if you also load `ggplot2` in the same session, the ggplot `layer` function will hide the lattice `layer`.  So I need to call this function as `LL + latticeExtra::layer(...)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it without `latticeExtra`. Admittedly, it's more complicated and difficult than the `latticeExtra` route. However, the flexibility with this `trellis.focus` method might be more useful in other contexts.

```
barchart(yield ~ variety | site, data = barley,
               groups = year, stack = TRUE,
               between=list(y=0.5),
               scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)))

panels  = trellis.currentLayout()
for( i in seq_along(panels) ) {
  ind = which( panels == i, arr.ind=TRUE )
  trellis.focus("panel",ind[2],ind[1])
  vars = trellis.panelArgs()
  panel.text(vars$x,vars$y,round(vars$y,0))
}
```

[image: Output of code above]